# where is mod_cache in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, webserver

Trying to turn on cache with apache 2.4.7 but I can't find the mod_cache or mod_disk_cache in the mods-available directory. How can I download/install it?

Comment: Same issue here. It was mentioned in the [upgrading guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) that mod_mem_cache was removed in 2.4, but I can't find mod_cache_disk as the guide suggests either.